# Is it possible to have export to excel button in a bot?

Tags: c#, button, frameworks, copy, bots

We are writing a bot,where in one of the response we show result in a tabular form.

We would like to give Export to excel button as an option to user to export it.

Or we can have a Copy button that copies the content in clipboard.

Is it possible to achieve using Microsoft Bot framework using C#.

Comment: If you're using the bot to call a new form, then it's dependent on the form (I believe. Not sure enough to post as answer). Have you tried adding the button already? What was the outcome? What went wrong?

Comment: Can you return a text file, or put text on to the clipboard.  If you can, then you can return an Excel file (but, you'd need to create it - don't use the Excel object model).  Putting Excel data on the clipboard would be interesting.  What I do when I want to put columnar data on the clipboard is put stuff as text in CSV format (actually, tab-separated-value, not comma-separated).  Excel usually swallows it whole, Word will allow the user to easily create a table from the text (Insert-Table-Convert text to table).